# React Native, Redux, Updates Overwrite initialState, Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-redux

I am attempting to have default information in my User reducer and then add my Firebase login response to that default information.  For example:

```
let userDefaultState = {startingNumber: 0}
const user = (state = userDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESET_USER':
            return userDefaultState
        case 'LOGIN':
            return action.payload
        case 'SET_MY_FEED':
            return { ...state, myFeed: action.payload }
        case 'UPDATE_FEED':
            return { ...state, myFeed: [action.payload, ...state.myFeed]}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

However, when I dispatch 'LOGIN', it fires Firebase.db.collection('user').doc(uid).get() and overwrites the current state with the response (ie payload) instead of adding it to the existing object.  I believe it is because of the way the 'LOGIN' case is set up.

The following is incorrect but I think it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
return { ...state, [action.payload, ...state]}
```

Desired outcome would be something like this:

```
user = { 
//Firebase response
"username": "name", "email": "email@email.com",
//userDefaultState
"startingNumber": 0
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Your problem is a bit unclear but maybe you just want `return { ...state, ...action.payload }` in LOGIN.

Comment: Sorry about the clarity but you did it anyway!  Thanks!